# Can someone explain why the assigned object inside forEach loop becomes null when it exits the forEach loop?

Tags: java, object, foreach, nullpointerexception, assign

When i assign a object to an existing object in the foreach loop it is present, but when it exits the loop it suddenly becomes null and throws an nullpointerexception

```
Project project = new Project();
for (Project prjct: pps.getProjects()) {

    if (prjct.getCode().equals(projectCode)) {
       project = prjct;

       System.out.println("First occurrence : " + project.toString()); //The object is present here

    } else if (!prjct.getCode().equals(projectCode)) {
       project = null;
    }

    System.out.println("Second occurrence : " + project.toString()); //Object is also present here
}
System.out.println("Third occurrence : " + project.toString()); //Throws NullPointerException
```

Comment: Please [edit] your post and add a [MRE], together with sample inputs.

Comment: It should work as is. My guess is that you're entering the ```else if``` block at the last iteration of the loop without realizing it.

Comment: @user85421 the reason for the null part is so when i am using the object i can test whether its null before using it with an if statement. im new here so i have a lot to learn

Comment: Side issue: Writing ```if (X) … else if (! X) …``` is redundant.  The only case where the ```else``` clause is going to execute is if the ```if``` condition is false.  That is, we know that ```X``` is false, so ```! X``` must be true, and thus no need to check whether ```! X``` is true. Thus ```if (X) … else …``` is sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are updating `project` on every pass of the loop.

It doesn't "suddenly become null" when you exit the loop; you are setting it to null on the last pass of the loop.

```
else if (!prjct.getCode().equals(projectCode)) {
    project = null;
}
```

Without running your program, it is still obvious that `prjct.getCode()` does not equal `projectCode`, because you are entering the `else if` block and setting `project = null`.

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, i found the issue.. after my forEach loop found the right object in the if statement, i should've used an break. didn't know that was possible.. i'll leave this for those who need it

Comment: Nevermind doesn't really sound like the right response considering the amount of attention given to your problem. Which looks like led you in the right direction. .. Anyway i upvoted.